# setting radio button checked under multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tabs, radio-button

i have few tabs and each tab has same radio button groups like this
[image]

see case#1 has radio buttons `name="managerid"` and with `class="managerid`

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="managerid" class="managerid managerid_8" data-radio="iradio_square-grey" value="8">
    &nbsp;Spam Dead
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="managerid" class="managerid managerid_9" data-radio="iradio_square-grey" value="9">
    &nbsp;Stewart Stephenson
</label>
```

these are dynamically generated tabs and radio buttons
now i want to set radio button checked in each tabs with the value

this is how im doing

```
$.each($("#tab_"+r.id).find(".managerid"),function(i,v){
    if(v.value === r.managerid){
        v.checked = true;
    }
});
```

i know the id of the tab so i `find()` the managerid and set them checked if the value matches

the problem is that it sets radio checked on the last tab only
how do i set radios checked on each tab with different values

Comment: The problem is because all the radio input have the same name, hence are in a group, so you can only select 1 of them. For this to work, the radio inputs in each tab will need to have separate names, eg. `case1-managerid`, `case2-managerid` etc.

Comment: they are generated from a template file so i cant change their names, is there any other way i can do it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Grouping radio inputs by name is a HTML standard which is controlled by the browser.

Comment: so there is no way except i change it from radio to select may be ;S i really wanted it radio

Comment: You could do that, but then you would have to write code to validate that only a single checkbox (for example) was chosen within a given tab. It would be much easier to find a way to do this in your templating

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to assign different style class to radio button controls and that is a better possible way to select/deselect across multiple tabs

Comment: Need to assign group wise different name for radio button.

Comment: I would prefer going by classes as it becomes flexible enough if radio buttons across different tabs need to selected by default when the page is loaded.